# Validate the date in html drop-down list

Tags: javascript, html, validation, date

I have three HTML drop down lists to select year, month and a date. If the selected year is equal to the current year second and third lists only show month and date up to the current date.
I want to code this in javascript.
Here the problem i am facing is, when the user select date or month at first how will it execute?

Comment: Post your code and someone can help you

Comment: I think you have to limit the date range. If you give better explanation then I can help. Better make a fiddle

Comment: Codes speak more than just mere words..post your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example below. If month and day are selected first, they will not change unless the selected value is no longer valid.  If they are not valid, they will reset to 1.

HTML

```
<body>
  <select name="month" id="month"></select>
  <select name="day" id="day"></select>
  <select name="year" id="year"></select>
</body>
```

JavaScript (w/JQuery)

```
<script type ="text/javascript" src="http://code.jQuery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var year = new Date().getFullYear();
  // load years
  for (var i=2000; i<=year; i++) $("#year").append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
  // load months
  for (var i=1; i<=12; i++) $("#month").append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
  // load days
  for (var i=1; i<=31; i++) $("#day").append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
});

$(function() {
  $('#year').change(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    if ($('#year').val()==now.getFullYear()) {
      $('#month option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val()>(now.getMonth()+1)) $(this).remove();
      });
    } else {
      for (var i=1; i<13; i++)
        if ($("#month option[value='" + i + "']").val()==undefined)
          $("#month").append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
    }

    checkMonth();
  });

  $('#month').change(checkMonth);
});

function checkMonth() {
  var now = new Date();
  if ($('#year').val()==now.getFullYear() && $('#month').val()==(now.getMonth()+1)) {
    $('#day option').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val()>now.getDate()) $(this).remove();
    });
  } else {
    var days = 31;
    var month = $('#month').val();
    if (month==2) {
      if (($('#year').val() % 4) == 0) days = 29; // leap year
      else days = 28;
    } else if (month==2 || month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11) {
      days = 30;
    }
    for (var i=1; i<32; i++)
      if (i>days)
        $("#day option[value='" + i + "']").remove();
      else if ($("#day option[value='" + i + "']").val()==undefined)
        $("#day").append('<option value=' + i + '>' + i + '</option>');
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? try with this url hope this will helps you 
Demo - >

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/jsdemo/JSDatePicker.html

Source - > 
 https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/JavaScript_Examples.html

Comment: That example isn't even correct.  it allows you to pick feb 30th for any year, and never allows you to pick the 31st for any month